# Error when trying to explore my files and Folder of my Drive

Tags: prism

I am trying to explore my files and Folder of my Drive But I am getting error.I have written a method to get my drive details and then a method to have a details of my drive(i.e Files and Folder)

1. Error at  Set Property of DirectoryList: An exception
   of type "System.StackOverflowException" was thrown.

Here is my Code:

```
public class FilePath
    {
        public string  FileName { get; set; }

        public string inputFilePath { get; set; }

    }
```

public class OpenDataViewModel : BindableBase
{

```
    public OpenDataViewModel()
    {
        ListDrives();            
    }

    private FilePath _selecteddirectory;
    public FilePath SelectedDirectory
    {
        get { return _selecteddirectory; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _selecteddirectory, value);
            ListDirectoryContent(_selecteddirectory);
        }
    }

    public List<FilePath> _directoryList;
    public List<FilePath> DirectoryList
    {
        get { return _directoryList; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _directoryList, value); }
    }



    private List<FilePath> _fileList;
    public List<FilePath> FileList
    {
        get { return _fileList; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _fileList, value); }
    }

    public void ListDrives()
    {


        DirectoryList = new List<FilePath>();


        foreach (var drive in Directory.GetLogicalDrives())
        {
            DirectoryList.Add(new FilePath()
            {
                
                FileName = drive.Remove(1, drive.LastIndexOf('\\') ) ,

                inputFilePath = Convert.ToString(drive)
            }); 
        }
      
    }

    public void ListDirectoryContent(FilePath inputPath)
    {
        
        
            DirectoryList = new List<FilePath>();


        foreach (var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(inputPath.inputFilePath))
        {
            DirectoryList.Add(new FilePath()
            {

                FileName = directory.Remove(0,3),

                inputFilePath = Convert.ToString(directory)
            });

        }

       
        
        FileList = new List<FilePath>();


        foreach (var fileData in Directory.GetFiles(inputPath.inputFilePath))
        {
            FileList.Add(new FilePath()
            {

                FileName = fileData.Remove(0, 3),

                inputFilePath = Convert.ToString(fileData)
            }) ;
        }           
    }
```

Here is my Xmal:

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DirectoryList}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Background="Aqua" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedDirectory}" >
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileName}" Header="Folder" Width="250" ></GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When setting `SelectedDirectory` you update `DirectoryList` which in turn causes `ListView` to update `SelectedDirectory`, thus your `StackOverflowException`.

You want to change at least to things:

1. update `DirectoryList` only if the selected directory actually changes
2. make to `FilePath` instances pointing to the same file equal

Ad 1:

```
public FilePath SelectedDirectory
{
    get => _selecteddirectory;
    set
    {
        if (SetProperty(ref _selecteddirectory, value))
            ListDirectoryContent(_selecteddirectory);
    }
}
```

Ad 2:

Implement `operator==` and `Equals` and make it a `readonly struct` instead of a `class`.

Comment: Thankyou so much for the answer. Also I am trying to have a back Button , I tried this  private DelegateCommand _goBackCommand;
        public DelegateCommand GoBackCommand =>  _goBackCommand ?? (_goBackCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteGoBackCommand));

        void ExecuteGoBackCommand()
        {               _selectedDirectory.InputFilePath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(SelectedDirectory.InputFilePath, ".."));
            ListDirectoryContent(_selectedDirectory);  }         But I am getting error that Selected directory get return null. Could you please help me.

Comment: Comments aren't a good place for questions or answers, I suggest you post a new question.

Comment: sorry I wrote my question in this way but the question was releted to this .