# Q: Navigate a folder Up using Prism Library

Tags: prism

refering to this Question [Error when trying to explore my files and Folder of my Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71460656/error-when-trying-to-explore-my-files-and-folder-of-my-drive/71465834#71465834). But I am getting error that Selected directory get return null. Could you please help me.

I want to have a Back Button. I tried this Code:

```
private DelegateCommand _goBackCommand;
public DelegateCommand GoBackCommand =>
_goBackCommand ?? (_goBackCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteGoBackCommand));
    
void ExecuteGoBackCommand()
{
 _selectedDirectory.InputFilePath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(SelectedDirectory.InputFilePath, ".."));
 ListDirectoryContent(_selectedDirectory);
 ListDrives();
 }
```

Xmal:

```
<Button x:Name="BackButton" Command="{Binding GoBackCommand}" Content="Back" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Background="Pink" FontSize="10">
```

Comment: What's `GoBackCommand` expected to do when no directory is selected? Why do you need to do anything but setting `SelectedDirectory` (not `_selectedDirectory`)?

Comment: @Haukinger GoBack Command  should show list of drives when no directory is selected.

Comment: @Haukinger I want to go inside the folder or drives and then when clicking the button then it return back .